# Strange problem with mysql_connect and mysql_selectdb not taking some variables as arguments

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I was working in some code in a PHP course I assisted, in a LAMP environment, and worked without problems. After the course, I took my code home and ran it on a WAMPServer, and for some reason, mysql_connect is not accepting some variables as arguments. I know this because I tried giving the parameters to mysql_connect by hand and the connection works. Also, I echoed all four variables and they print out OK.

I am new to PHP, but this doesnt make any sense to me.

The code:

functions.php

```
 <?php

require ("config.php");
     function conectardb () { 
     mysql_connect ($server, $login, $pass);
     mysql_select_db ($db);
 }

?>


config.php

<?php
 $login = "root" ;
 $pass = "" ;
 $server = "localhost";
 $db = "testing";
?>
```

I've tried replacing the plain arguments by their variables one by one, and found out the code works until this point:

```
 function conectardb () { 
     mysql_connect ($server, "root", $pass);
     mysql_select_db ("testing");
 }
```

If I use $login or $db, the connection will not work. Any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of scope in PHP.

Functions exist in their own scope. You defined `$login`, `$pass`, etc. in a different scope than the function. The function can't access them, it can't see them.

You can do a couple things about this:

1. Define the database connection parameters as constants instead of variables
2. Define the variables within the function (requiring the configuration file inside the function will have the same effect)
3. Use the `global` keyword to pull them from the global scope into the function scope

i.e.

```
$bar = 'hello world';
function foo() {
    global $bar;
    echo $bar;
}
```

Comment: Great!! The other answers were valid as well, but since this is the first I will comment here: I suspected something like this, but didnt understand why $pass and $server worked. Any ideas?? I put the require inside the function and it worked, but I would still want to know why. Also, which one of the options would be the best (in a "best practice" sense, I mean)?

Comment: @0al0: Typical, since these would be considered constants throughout your application, it's customary to use [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) for server information (e.g. database name, username, password).

Comment: @0al0 It only "worked" in the sense that if you don't give `mysql_connect` a hostname, it will try `localhost` on its own, and you actually have an empty password. Nothing really worked, you didn't actually pass any variables, they were empty and emptiness was equal to the actual settings for your situation.

Comment: Thank you Dan, makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is variable scope.

Unlike most languages, php doesn't automatically know about variables defined outside of a function. To access these you need to specify them as either `global $server, $pass, $db;` within the function, or use the `$_GLOBALS[]` variables.

Please see:

- [PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (See how PHP manages scope)
- [`$_GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) (Global variables, which permits visibility within functions)
- [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) (For global constants, which would have visibility within functions)

Answer (score 2):

```
require ("config.php");
function conectardb () 
{ 
    global $server, $login, $pass, $db;
    mysql_connect ($server, $login, $pass);
    mysql_select_db ($db);
}
```

This should do the trick since variables are defined in a different scope. However, I recommend passing requires values as parameters.

```
function conectardb ($server, $login, $pass, $db) 
{ 
    mysql_connect ($server, $login, $pass);
    mysql_select_db ($db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@David Kuridža I recommend to not use mysql_ components and use mysqli or PDO extensions which of these two are included by default.

Comment: Realizing your reputation doesn't permit comments yet, this is not suitable as an "Answer" post. Your comment is valid, but please refrain from posting off-topic comments as answers.

Comment: Agreed, but the question was why above code doesn't work, and since 0al0 said s/he is beginning with PHP, it was appropriate to explain both the scope and parameters. Adding PDO to the answer was not necessary in my opinion.